# How can I modify this php script to list all php files in recursive directories of size 'x' to 'y'?

Tags: php, search, find

I have a script I found somewhere which searches my web hosting directory (from where the php script file is into all directories below it) recursively for malware type content.

I would like to just modify it so it will simply supply me with a list of 'php' files that suspect are my most likely group to be hacker

files: example file name: list.php which is always between 340Kb and 550kb.

If I can simply end up with a listing of the files that meet my criteria, it will speed my eradication of them where ever they are found (most times just randomly dropped all over the place by these hackers).

I need to try to sanitize the entire public_html dir and every dir and file beneath it.

Too difficult to search every single dir manually. It's super time consuming.

Can you help me?

How would I write a simple php file to look for these files?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php Use this, it is amazing, especially when attached to a `RecursiveFilterIterator`

Comment: Show the code you have already that you want to modify

Comment: ok. That is a great link... but I will need a programmer to help me. I have no idea how to structure it correctly to look for only php files that are between 300K and 550K in file size.

Comment: Can't figure out how to paste in the code without this site complaining it is not formatted 'correctly'.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than attempt to recreate something already well documented, I would recommend that you look at the content at this link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php , This link directly addresses your question and has some great examples of recursive directory functions.